# Block code execution at it's root

Tags: c#, optimization, conditional-statements

**What i want to do**

I'm trying to write optimized function caller which execution can be optional, which can be defined before compilation. without the user specifying at the start should it be executed of not.

**Possible solutions**

1. First is to use #define directives. The bad thing is the they would have to be added and closed for *every* LogMessage call, which is what i dont want to use.
2. Second solution is to use [Conditional("")] but that would also require adding it before *every* function call.
3. Is to use directives inside function block, but that would sacrifice performance. About this more in the **example**.

**Example**

Consider this example. It does everything I want - user calls LogMessage("whatever") and before compilation i specify should it be executed in the build.

```
LogMessage("whatever");

public static void LogMessage(string message){
#if LOG
   ///execute log
#endif
}
```

Problem is that string **"whatever"** is created before - regardless of will it be executed or not. I dont want to allow string creation and/or construction such as LogMessage(someNUmber+" is "+otherNumber); if should not happen.

**Final Point**
Im trying to find solution in which LogMessage would be canceled - blocked at it's root, without adding directives before. I was thinking maybe some sort of reflection search before compilation would do it, but im not really sure.

Thanks, 
I hope somebody can shed some light in the right direction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485029/convenient-way-for-conditional-logging/38485369, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036258/prevent-expensive-log-call-if-log-level-is-below-threshold

Comment: This doesn't qualify for an answer, so im adding it as a comment: The only option I see is IL Weaving. Have a look at Frameworks like Fody.

Comment: Do you really have code where every CPU instruction is so valuable? Or you just *think* that quick in-memory check whether log level is enabled will hit your performance? Also why not scale your application horizontally instead of fighting for each CPU instruction?

Comment: @CodeCaster Adding primitive condition check before every Log call is exactly what id prefer not to do.

Comment: @nozzleman Interesting suggestion, ill research this possibility +1

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy "Why are you even doing this" is not open for discussion, as much as id like it to be. We have requirements which must be executed.

Comment: I don't know where you stopped reading, but one of the suggestions is to introduce an `Action<string>` overload, so `Logger.Log(() => "Expensive" + "String" + "Concatenation))"`. See also aspect-oriented programming where the `if()`s are injected pre- or post-compile.

Comment: Fair point, but if you must write Action prefix then writing if(condition) wouldn't seem a big difference, and a lot understandable that's for sure.

Comment: @CodeCaster Aspect-oriented programming seem like the easiest solution, ill look into it +1

Comment: @Scavs just FIY: Fody is an AOP Framework, so im totally in with CodeCaster ;)